# Prevent automatic browswer JS execution when modifying DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a code container,

```
<div class="codeblock"> ... </div>
```

Which should store HTML and JS data, more specifically this Twitter embed code:

```
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet"> ... </blockquote>
<script> ... </script>
```

However when adding this code immediately triggers the script and replaces the whole blockquote and script with:

```
<twitterwidget> ... </twitterwidget>
```

This is the expected behaviour as specified here: https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-tweets/faq

**How can I prevent the execution of JS inside this element?** I need to keep the original piece of code.

Comment: Not sure what you mean... Don't you mean just escape the script tags so the browser doesn't execute it? `&lt;script&gt;...`

Comment: The moment you add a `<script>` tag to a website, it will be executed. Couldn't you add it later?

Comment: You'll have to show how you add the HTML now. If you do it with `.html()` then use `.text()` instead.

Comment: @JJJ Thanks, but I can't use ´text()´ or ´value´ because it would then become a string. The code block is both editable and executable.

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent a `<script>` element from executing by setting the `type` to a value which does not identify any real scripting language. A simple way of doing this would be to prefix the actual value with the word "disabled":

```
<script type="disabled text/javascript">
    …
</script>
```

You will then need to check for this value and strip it when saving the HTML document.